# How to disable an extra window to restart system even after selecting not to do so in files in use dialog in installshield

Tags: installshield, installshield-2012

I am doing an upgrade for the existing exe file using installshield. when installing the update , in files in use dialog I select the option to automatically close and restart the application instead of the other option to reboot the system.
But I get an extra window which tells me to restart the system again after installation is complete. How to disable this window? Please help :)

Comment: If you still have problems after trying the new command lines, please read my comments here on the crazy things people do to avoid reboot - don't try any of it, just read my comment on the original question (describing custom actions and reboots): http://superuser.com/questions/428717/is-there-a-really-really-really-dont-reboot-parameter-for-msiexec

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run the installation silently with REBOOT=ReallySuppress (update the paths). Please note that I haven't had the chance to test all these command lines:

```
msiexec.exe /I "C:\IsWiX.msi" /QN /L*V "C:\msilog.log" REBOOT=ReallySuppress
```

- /I is for install
- /QN is silent mode
- /L* is verbose logging

If you have an EXE file instead of an MSI file I would extract the MSI to an administrative image (file extract from setup.exe basically) using the following command:

```
setup.exe /a
```

Then specify an extract location for the files in the EXE file. You can also run it directly with the [**Installshield command lines for EXE files**](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield20helplib/Content/helplibrary/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm). Something like:

```
Setup.exe /v"REBOOT=ReallySuppress /qn"
```

Or silently with logging:

```
Setup.exe /v"/l*v c:\test.log REBOOT=ReallySuppress /qn"
```

There are also some [simplified command line macros from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Most of the time these can be used. Other times you need the [full command line interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I don't want to run the installation silently, I just want to hide the last windows which tells the end user to reboot even after selecting the option automatically close and restart the app during upgrade.

Comment: You can run `Setup.exe /v"REBOOT=ReallySuppress"` if it is an exe file, or `msiexec.exe /I "C:\YourFile.msi" REBOOT=ReallySuppress` if it is an MSI.