# How to let msi package install process take place in cmd instead of windows installer gui

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-installer, command-prompt

How can I make a batch file that automatically installs java,office and adobe stuff without gui, instead of that I want to let whole proces take place inside the command prompt. For example I want to have a bar inside the command prompt telling me how far the install process is. How do I make that, I can't find it on the internet. Here is a example of what I already have:

```dos
@echo off
echo Installing application...
msiexec.exe /passive /i "%~dp0skypesetup.msi"
echo Install failed.
pause
```

Here I have the msi file if you wanna help me: http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-msi

Does anyone knows how to make a program with percent bar inside the command promt?

Comment: Run `msiexec.exe /?` and you get displayed a list of options. Instead of `/passive` it is better to use `/quiet`. As far as I know Microsoft installer does not support a progess bar in console window. Best for silent (quiet) installations is always contacting the producing company of the software and ask how to install the software quiet with or without customizations as there are most likely not two software products with identical installer scripts (options). And finally such questions are better asked on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) as not about programming, just using right options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the **external GUI** you can check [**MsiSetExternalUI function**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25116048/129130) (follow the links). For installing silently the basic msiexec.exe command line is:

```
msiexec.exe /I "C:\MsiFile.msi" /QN /L*V "C:\msilog.log"
```

**Quick explanation**:

```
/I is for install 
/QN is silent mode
/L*V is verbose logging
```

**Some links**:

- [Silent Install of MSI](https://serverfault.com/questions/30068/silent-install-of-msi/67001)
- [What is different about a silent installation session](https://serverfault.com/questions/590795/difference-between-isntalling-a-msi-using-invoke-wmimethodvia-a-cmd-file-and/614653#614653)
- [Common msiexec.exe command lines](http://ss64.com/nt/msiexec.html)
- [Here is an answer that discusses alternative ways to install a package without using msiexec.exe](https://serverfault.com/a/596519/20599)
- [How to disable an extra window to restart system even after selecting not to do so in files in use dialog in installshield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339642/how-to-disable-an-extra-window-to-restart-system-even-after-selecting-not-to-do)

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me :( , I'v searched a lot and finally found it. I thought I had to use msi but I can also do it with .exe files. Stupid me.
Here's the code if someone wants it or needs it:

```
@ECHO OFF
echo Do you want to install ccleaner
pause
ccleaner.exe /S /L=1043
echo You've succesfully installed ccleaner
pause
```